# How to bind control with function keys

Tags: key-bindings

How does one bind functions to `C-<f#>` where `<f#>` is any of the function keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some searching around finally found [Xah Lee's site](http://xahlee.info/emacs/emacs/emacs_keybinding_power_of_keys_sequence.html)

Turns out it's just

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-<f9>") 'function)
```

Comment: Or simply the emacs manual https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Function-Keys.html or in emacs alt-x info and the search for function key - emacs comes from a time before web searches and has its own documentation as part of itself.